Is there any reference about critical rationalism with respect to historiography?
I am interested in history of the science and mathematics, and I wonder whether critical rationalism was ever suggested as a method by which to do history of the sciences or mathematics? Does it even make sense to apply critical rationalism to history? what would it mean? Would it mean to document controversaries or refutations? Would appreciate any references relevant to critical rationalism + history + historiography + mathematics or sciences. 

Critical rationalist historiography would involve treating historical controversies and refutations. Popper wrote a lot of that kind of material. There is a lot of material like that in "The open society and its enemies", such as the extensive discussions of what problems Popper thought Plato was trying to solve. There are also discussions like that in "Conjectures and Refutations" Chapters 1-3, 5-8, 11 and 15. He also wrote a whole book on the presocratics "The World of Parmenides: Essays on the Presocratic Enlightenment".
Lakatos' book "Proofs and Refutations" also has some discussion of the history of the philosophy of mathematics in Appendix 1, which is about the history of various ideas about continuity.
